# when the thread will suspend a suspend-function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I am just learning about Kotlin's Coroutines, and I'm curious when the thread will suspend a suspend-function. In Golang, we know it will suspend a goroutine in several cases; calling another goroutine, block-syscall, channeling, gc. Is Kotlin's coroutine the same?

Comment: What have you researched? Including what you have researched gives us an idea about what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research...

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin the rule is extremely simple: a coroutine never suspends on its own, you must explicitly write code to make it suspend. In most usage scenarios this code is buried within the functions you call, though. Here's a simple example:

```
val result = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    makeAsyncCall(onComplete = { continuation.resume(it) })
}
```